Windows 10 subsystem ubuntu password lost. How to sign in as root?
I have a Ubuntu Linux subsystem (wsl) installed in my personal Microsoft Windows 10 laptop. However, when the Ubuntu was installed, somehow the password was unknown (or no password at all). I have never changed the password to root, and only tried to use "sudo" to install some software. However, I stuck because I didn't know the password for root. Because of this problem, Ubuntu was uninstalled and then installed again, but the OS remembered everything. Thus, the problem can't be solved in this way.
I have done some research on the Internet, but all the solutions couldn't work in the Windows 10 subsystem (Ubuntu as the OS), which has no way to be booted into a recovery mode.
Any help on this issue would be appreciated.
I am expecting that I could log into the Ubuntu installed in Windows 10 subsystem as a root user so I could install some software into this Ubuntu OS environment.

Did you change the password to root or a different password. Your question isn’t clear in this regard. By default there isn’t a password for root unless you intentionally set it

I have done this many times in the past successfully. In normal situations, while a user's account is being created (see the information in the link given below in the "answer" area), you will be asked to create a user name and a password. If you need to install a software using "sudo", you will be asked for the root password. This password would be the password you create for this first user account (Let's say it is a personal PC. Thus, only one user.) The problem I got here is that I don't know the user's password for some reason. Thus, I don't know the password for the root either.

Because it is a subsystem in windows 10, no way to boot this ubuntu subsystem into a recovery mode.

"Did you change the password to root or a different password" --- I don't know the password. Thus, there is no way for me to set or change the password.

I asked if you changed it. There is no password to root unless you change it. The default user also isn't root unless you set the default user to root. So, I am asking if you changed the password to root.  Try wsl -d Ubuntu -u root.  The only way root would have a password is if you ran the passwd command as root. Instead of temporary comment [edit] your question with enough information to answer your question.

Take a look at the Microsoft documentation at Set up your Linux username and password. There is a section to reset the password.

If you forgot the password for your Linux distribution:
Open PowerShell and enter the root of your default WSL distribution
using the command: wsl -u root
[If you need to update the forgotten password on a distribution that is
not your default, use the command: wsl -d <distribution> -u root,
replacing  with the name of your targeted distribution.]
Once your WSL distribution has been opened at the root level inside
PowerShell, you can use this command to update your password: passwd <username> where  is the username of the account in the
distribution whose password you've forgotten.
You will be prompted to enter a new UNIX password and then confirm
that password. Once you're told that the password has updated
successfully, close WSL inside of PowerShell using the command:
exit.


Right now this is a link-only answer. Please remember that this site requires all information necessary for the answer to be posted in the answer, with links used for attribution or further research. Please EDIT your post to fix this.

Based on the documentation from the link, "To change or reset your password, open the Linux distribution and enter the command: passwd. You will be asked to enter your current password". The problem I got is that I don't know the current password, and there is no way to put a windows10 Ubuntu subsystem into a recovery mode for the password reset.

@TangY Read the next paragraph after that one that starts with "If you forgot the password for your Linux distribution," as shown in M. Behrens' edit to this answer.

Thanks for adding the link info to the post.
